# ASP.NET application target framwork 4.5 on windows server 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2022

I'm trying to setup a ASP.NET web application that is targeting framework 4.5 on a windows server 2022. For some reason it doesn't work.

The documentation says that the preinstalled version framework 4.8 should cover all 4.x versions. And, even when you try to install 4.5 you get the message:

"Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5 redistributable.

Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been installed on this computer."

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: _"I'm trying to setup a ASP.NET web application that is targeting framework 4.5 on a windows server 2022. For some reason it doesn't work."_ I'm sorry, but this is too vague. Please be _very_ specific on -what you are trying, -what steps you have taken, -what is actually happening (including error messages), end - what you expected to happen

Comment: I get 404 directory not found when I try to access the web application. There is actually nothing in the IIS logs that helps. My first thought was that you can't run an old 4.5 on a new Windows Server 2022. And it has to do with the preinstalled framework version 4.8. That it doesn't cover old applications running on 4.5.

Comment: Help us troubleshoot with you. Eg. 404 means "not found". Confirm IIS is mapped to the right folder. If you put an index.html file in that folder, does it work? Have you tried from localhost? Do NT logs have any errors from IIS? Do IIS logs also show 404 errors?  Are you requiring authentication to your IIS? Is there an F5 (or other load balancer). Could it be a DNS problem?

Comment: What is the `protocol sub-status` of the 404 error in IIS? You will probably see it is `sc-substatus` if you're looking at the log file

Comment: It is mapped to the right folder. An index.html shows. And there is a 404 log in IIS. To me it seems, that the ASP.NET app simply doesn't execute. And I understand it as a problem with the framework. It doesn't seem to compile on the server.

Comment: when you setup IIS did you select the ASP.NET 4 option?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no general generic solution to these kind of problems. The application needs to be debugged, possibly on the target system. With the little information you provide is, we cannot help you